# Can't properly echo code with PHP

Tags: php, nested, conditional-statements, user-agent

I'm trying to set up a conditional system which programatically detects both the browser (using the `USER_AGENT` string) and the platform (using PHP-Mobile-Detect). My current setup looks roughly like this:

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<?php
include("Mobile_Detect.php");
$detect = new Mobile_Detect();
?>
    <?php if($detect->isiPad()) {
        echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style/iPad.css" type="text/css">';
    }

    else 
    {
        echo '<meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" type="text/css">;
        if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Chrome') !== false)
            {
                echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="../style/splash-webkit.css" type="text/css">';
            }
        //and so on for other browsers
        [etc]'
    }
```

The obvious problem that occurs here, is the conflict between the `'`s. The `echo` under `else`, rather than ending at the end of my `<style>` tag, as I would want it to, ends at the first `'` to appear in the code, which, as it were, is in the first `USER_AGENT` declaration.
How can I bypass this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You missed a `'` at the end of this line:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" type="text/css">;
```

Replace it with:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" type="text/css">';
```

You are using single and double quotes nicely though. However, if you *do* need to use the same quotes, you can always escape them with a `\`. For example, this would also work:

```
echo '<meta charset=\'UTF-8\'>';
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this and let me know then

```
else 
{
echo '<meta charset="UTF-8"><link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" type="text/css">';
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Chrome') !== false)
{
echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="../style/splash-webkit.css" type="text/css">';
}
//and so on for other browser
}
```

Comment: Your method worked as well, but considering that I've got several pages with this type of code (I'm considering an include at this point), Fluffeh's solution is easier.